# How to add adapter on GraphQL to transform snake case to camelCase in schemas

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I need some serious help here. I'm using the AWS Amplify Framework, and I've added a GraphQL data source using the command `amplify api add-graphql-datasource` (I'm using Aurora Serverless). My database uses plural for tables name and snake case for columns and because of that the generated schemas are all messed up:

```
type users {
  id: Int!
  email: String
  first_name: String
  last_name: String
  phone_number: String
  created_at: AWSDateTime!
  updated_at: AWSDateTime!
}
```

Would it be possible to install an adapter or something to use GraphQL conventions? There is no possibility to change the tables and columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert snake\_case to camelCase field names in apollo-server-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881054/convert-snake-case-to-camelcase-field-names-in-apollo-server-express)