# How to camelCase my responses' fields and tables in Hausra or ApolloClient?

Tags: apollo-client, hasura

In my aplications I use Hasura for my graphql server and Apollo for the client. I have a postgres schema with snake_case table and field names, but I want to have camelCases keys in my responses' objects. Any known way to achieve that?
I can see that apollo server offers fieldResolver where it can be done([Convert snake_case to camelCase field names in apollo-server-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881054/convert-snake-case-to-camelcase-field-names-in-apollo-server-express)), but I found no similar option for Hasura/ApolloClient.

Comment: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a long story short - currently, there is no such a solution for Hasura. The best suggestion I could get was to rename the column names manually, one-by-one via the console => DATA section => Modify tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can **expose** any column with a different name in the GraphQLAPI without you having to rename the column itself...
you can do that in the **hasura console** as in the picture below[image]

Answer (score -1):

> Any way to achieve that?

Check out GraphQL aliases.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases
https://hasura.io/blog/customising-alias-graphql-fields-with-hasura/

Example:

```
# Query
query {
  users {
    id
    name: full_name
    email: email_addr
  }
}

# Response
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "3ea1352a-6654-444d-9357-62816ccbd2b3",
        "name": "Praveen",
        "email": "email@mydomain.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```